# The Tkinter button

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

I am trying to write a game that asks questions of defferent levels when clicking on one of the three buttons, but I keep getting the error "NameError: name 'useranswer' is not defined"

I have tried using making it a global variable, moving the submit function to different places in the code.

For example:

```
    import tkinter as tk

    root = Tk()

    #functions to be called by the buttons
    def get_question_lvl_one():
            try:
                    the_question = questions_lvl_one[-1]
                    questions_lvl_one.remove(the_question)
                    correct_answer = answer_lvl_one[-1]
                    answer_lvl_one.remove(correct_answer)
            except IndexError:
                    myquestion = None
                    print('end of game', file=sys.stderr)
            # This is the section of code which creates the new main window
            toplevel = Toplevel()
            toplevel.geometry('425x238')
            toplevel.configure(background='#F0F8FF')
            toplevel.title('Question')
            toplevel.focus_set()
            # This is the section of code which creates the a label
            Label(toplevel, text='Question', bg='#F0F8FF', font=('courier', 12, 'normal')).place(x=177, y=29)

            # This is the section of code which creates a text input box
            useranswer = tk.Entry(toplevel).place(x=146, y=105)
            #Submit Button
            Button(toplevel, text='Submit', bg='#F0E8FF', font=('arial', 12, 'normal'), command=submit).place(x=175, y=200)

    def submit():
            global useranswer
            answer = useranswer.get()
            if answer == correct_answer:
                    toplevel = Toplevel()
                    toplevel.geometry('425x238')
                    toplevel.configure(background='#F0H8FF')
                    toplevel.title('Correct')
                    toplevel.focus_set()
                    user_score += 1


    def main_window():
            # This is the section of code which creates the main window
            root.geometry('814x541')
            root.configure(background='#F0F8FF')
            root.title('Space Game')

            # This is the section of code which creates the level one button
            Button(root, text='1', bg='#00FFFF', font=('courier', 12, 'normal'), command=get_question_lvl_one).place(x=125, y=237)

    if __name__ == '__main__':
            main_window()
    root.mainloop()
```

Comment: There is a lot of code to look into, would be nice if you could just post the important parts and also the error code.

Comment: This code won't run. You import tkinter one way but try to use it another way. Plus, you refernece variables that don't exist like `questions_lvl_one` and `answer_lvl_one`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`useranswer` is a local variable in the function which creates it. It needs to be declared as global.

```
def get_question_lvl_one():
    global useranswer
    ...
```

You also need to make sure you define it properly. Your code is setting it to `None`. You need to define it like this:

```
useranswer = tk.Entry(toplevel)
useranswer.place(x=146, y=105)
```

Comment: I have tryed declaring it as a global variable in every possible place in my code, but it still gives me the NameError error.

Comment: @Lulianos: if that is so, then you are trying to use it before the code that defines it is called. However, when I fix the dozen or so issues that prevent your posted code from running at all, and then do what this answer suggests, I do not get the error you say you do.